# What does this error mean? ("Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist'")

Tags: release-loki, apt, software-sources

`apt update` gives me this error:

```
Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is only a warning about a file that has been renamed:

- you should either delete (move, backup) if you do not want its contents to be interpreted by `apt` or
- rename it (without `.ucf-dist` in the filename) so that its contents is interpreted by `apt`.

Comment: there was also a file called  `20auto-upgrades` at the same location, so that I have deleted `20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist`, and the warning ceased to appear.